# How to navigate the URL after booking page in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, url-routing, drupal-modules, drupal-content-types

I have content type booking and created booking page in drupal 7 and same page is displaying error, confirmation and booking page. I am trying to split into three different pages(nodes) using same booking content type. I am using custom module for booking.

After booking, I would like to redirect to xyz.com/booking-confirm if it's successfully booking and if it's error xyz.com/booking-error and currently, using xyz.com/booking for all actions.

Should I use header to redirect it?

```
header('Location: /booking-confirm'); 
header('Location: /booking-error');
```

Should I hook them in `template.php`?

```
function MYMODULE_user_register_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'path/to/somewhere';
}
```

I am not sure, which is correct option to figure it out. I would like to split the URL using same content type. Any approach to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Leave the template and headers out of it.

Use hooks hook_FORM_validate() and hook_form_submit in your custom module:

Example for form_submit:

```
function your_booking_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
$form_state['redirect'] = '/thank-you-page';
}

function your_booking_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
// if criteria is not met (user entered wrong data or whatever the validation you do) {
$form_state['redirect'] = '/error-page';
}
}
```

Comment: I have created custom module and adding this module. But, it did not work it out. Feel like, I am missing something.